# How to get multi css rule for ng-style by function?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

I need for apply multi css rule to html tag in angular form template.

```
<div class="form-control" id="data.objectStyle"  
  ng-model="data.type" 
  ng-style="getStyle(data.objectStyle)">
{{data.objectStyle.title}}
</div>
```

getStyle function in controller :

```
$scope.getStyle = function (taskType) {
    return {
         background-color:taskType.backColor,
         color: taskType.color,
         font-size:taskType.fontSize,
         font-family:taskType.font
    }
)};
```

taskType object:

```
{
    backColor:'#006',
    color:'#56DA',
    fontSize:12,
    font:'New Times Roman'
}
```

The `getStyle` function does not return a style! What to do?

Comment: You haven't included enough code. What does the function return? What are the values of `taskType.backColor` etc?

Comment: @Ed Hinchliffe taskType = {backColor:'#006',color:'#56DA',fontSize:12,font:'New Times Roman'}.

Comment: That should work then. Errors in the console?

Answer (score 15):

## EDIT

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) specify that you need to wrap your keys in quotation marks so they aren't invalid JSON object keys:

```
return {
     "background-color": taskType.backColor,
     "color": taskType.color,
     "font-size":taskType.fontSize,
     "font-family":taskType.font
}
```

---

#### Old Answer (not using ng-style)

While I never used [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle), it doesn't seem to take objects. Rather it is an equivalent of ng-class but for single styles.

Try changing your function to:

```
$scope.getStyle = function (taskType) {

        return {
         "background-color:"+taskType.backColor+
         ";color:"+ taskType.color+
         ";font-size:"+taskType.fontSize+
         ";font-family:"+taskType.font+";";
    }
)};
```

and the html to use the regular style tag with a bind:

```
<div class="form-control" id="data.objectStyle"  
ng-model="data.type" style="{{getStyle(data.objectStyle)}}">
```

Comment: @crmpicco, check the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) or ask a question, otherwise I can't help

Comment: I think this should work: `ng-style="getStyle(data.objectStyle)"`

Comment: @crmpicco, it should work given the keys are wrapped in quotes

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using? I'm using 1.0.7.

Comment: Actually you don't need to wrap properties in quotes - that's syntactically identical anyway. Nor do you need the semi-colons (in fact I'm surprised they'd work). It does now take objects. You can also camelCase eg; return { backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'blue'};

Comment: @cirrus, the docs still tell us to wrap keys in quotes. I do believe camelCase works as that is teh format in which the styles are stored on the DOM object, but I'm unsure if it will work for browser prefixes. [Angular Doc for ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) . And the semi colons were an old answer, not using the ng-style directive

Comment: i use AngularJS v1.2.6